# Suppose $m\mid (a-b).$ I want to prove that $m\mid (b-a)$ where $a, b, m$ are integers.

Tags: number-theory

I know that if $m\mid(a-b)$, then $a-b=mk$ where $k$ is an integer. And $a=b +mk.$ So does $m\mid [ (b+mk) -b] = m \mid mk$? I know $d\mid m$ iff $m= dk.$ So does $b= mk - a$? Then it would be $m \mid [( mk - a) - (b + mk)] = m | mk - a - b - mk = $? I know that if $m\mid (a-b)$ and $m\mid (b-a)$ are true, but I don’t know how to go on with my proof.

Comment: Suppose $m\mid (a-b)$, then $a-b=mk$ for some integer $k$.  It follows then that $b-a=m(-k)$...

Comment: How would you show that if $x$ divides $y$ then it also divides $-y$?

Comment: take absolute value

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The set of multiples of $m$ are not only closed under negation but also under subtraction and scaling, so more generally if $\,a,b\,$ are multiples of $m$ then so too is $\,j\,a + k\,b\,$ for all integers $\,j,k.\,$ It's very easy to prove and fundamental in number theory, e.g. see the [LCM universal Property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242)

Answer (score 1):

If m $\mid$ (a-b) then nm = a - b for some integer n. Now multiply both sides by -1. Then we have $$-nm = -(a-b) = b - a.$$ So we have that m $\mid$ b- a.