# if a prime p|LCM[a,b] then p|a or p|b

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Given a prime p show that if p|LCM[a,b] then p|a or p|b.

Is it enough for me to simply show that if d=LCM then d=an, then by Euclid(p|xy then p|x or p|y), p|d so p|an therefore p|a or p|n? and doing the same for b.

Also, how do I confirm the "or" here?

Thank you.

Comment: I think from $d|an$ you might just get $d|n$ and not $d|a.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\,\ p\mid {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid ab\:$ by the [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2322114/242) & transitivity of "divides".

Comment: sorry, but i'm a little confused at how you arrived to the conclusion above.
could you show how you arrived from the universal property, a,b∣m⟺lcm(a,b)∣m to the above?

Comment: @supremus_58 For $\,m = ab\,$ it says $\,a,b\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid ab,\,$ i.e. the lcm divides every common multiple $\,m\,$  of $\,a,b,\,$ so  in particular it divides the common multiple $\,m = ab.\ $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

$$\text{LCM}(a,b)=a\cdot\frac b{\text{GCD}(a,b)}$$Now use Euclid's result.