# $2i\equiv2j\pmod{\!m}\Rightarrow\,2i\equiv2j\pmod{\!2m}\, $ for odd $\,m\,$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $$2^6k+2\equiv4\pmod9$$
then this implies that $$2^6k+2\equiv4\pmod{18}$$since both sides are even.
Can anyone explain to me why this inference is true?

Comment: $9\mid 2n\Rightarrow\,9\mid n\Rightarrow 18\mid 2n\,$ by Euclid (or directly $\,9\mid n =  9n\!-\!4(2n)).\ $ In OP $\, 2n = 2^6k-2\ \ $

Comment: **Or** $ $ let $\,x = 2^6k\!+\!2,\,$ so $\,x\equiv 4\pmod{\!9\ \&\ 2}\Rightarrow x\equiv 4\pmod{\!18\!=\!{\rm lcm}(9,2)}\ $ by [CCRT = Constant-case Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) or [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) $\ \ $

Comment: **Or** $ $ $ 9\mid 2n\Rightarrow  2n\bmod 18 =  9(2n/9 \bmod 2) = 9(0/1) = 0\ $ by the [$\!\bmod$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

so $2^6k +2\equiv 4 \pmod 9$.

So there is an integer $m$ so that $2^6k + 2 = 4 + 9m$.

But the LHS is even so the RHS must be even which (because $9$ is odd) means that $m$ must be even.

SO there is an integer $n$ so that $k = 2n$ and ....

$2^6k + 2  = 4 + 9\cdot 2n = 4 + 18n$.

But that means $2^6k + 2 \equiv 4 \pmod {18}$.

......

ALternative explanation:

$2^6k + 2 \equiv 4\pmod 9 \implies$

$9|2^6k + 2 - 4$.  But $2^6k +2 -4$ is even so $2|2^6k+2-4$.  So both $2$ and $9$ divide $2^6+2 -4$ so then $\operatorname{lcm}(2,9) = 18$ also divides $2^6k +2-4$.

And as $18|2^6k + 2-4$ that is the very definiton of $2^6k + 2\equiv 4 \pmod {18}$.

=====

Lemma (for future use now that we did the above):  If $a\equiv b\pmod n$ and $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ then $a\equiv b \pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(k,n)}$

Pf: Same way we did the above.

Comment: i.e. $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\!n\ \&\ k}\iff a\equiv b\pmod{{\rm lcm}(n,k)}\ $ by [CCRT = Constant-case Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) or [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) $\ \ $