# Finding a generator of $nZ∩mZ$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to find a generator of $nZ∩mZ$.

My intuition:

A generator is $c = lcm(m,n)$.

Given some integer $a$ in the intersection $nZ∩mZ$, I know that there exists $x,y$ such that $a = xn$ and $a = ym$.

Now i want to show there exists $k$ such that $c^k = a$, But could no go further.

Any hints will be useful :)

Comment: It is not $c^k$ but $c k$. We are talking about an additive group.

Comment: @Gribouillis $c^k = ck$

Comment: Perhaps saying with words would work: "any element in $\;n\Bbb Z\cap m\Bbb Z\;$ is a multiple of $\;n\;$ and of $\;m\;$ , thus..."

Comment: Euclidean division shows that a non trivial additive subgroup of ${\mathbb Z}$ has the form $c {\mathbb Z}$ where $c$ is the smallest positive element. (by the way I don't agree that $c^k = c k$. It is ambiguous in this context)

Comment: Isn't the definition of $lcm(m,n)$ that it is a generator of the intersection ideal? ;-)

Comment: @aaabbb Don't mix multiplicative and additive notation.

Comment: @ancient That's one general  approach to defining lcm in general domains. The point of the question is to show that general definition is equivalent to the more specific definition in $\Bbb Z$ (or any Euclidean domain), where "least" is measured wrt to the Euclidean size measure ($|n|$ in $\Bbb Z,\,$ and $\deg f\,$ in $K[x]$), vs. [wrt to divisibility order](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) generally.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did  say it was a joke. ;-)